# Chameleon template engine: loop with index

Tags: python, css, twitter-bootstrap, pyramid, chameleon

I am practicing `Chameleon` template engine with `Bootstrap`. The layout I am currently using is [`Fluid layout`](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/fluid.html).

In the listing part of this layout, its using structure like

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">******</div>
    <div class="span4">******</div>
    <div class="span4">******</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">******</div>
    <div class="span4">******</div>
    <div class="span4">******</div>
</div>
```

Each `row-fluid` `div` contains exactly 3 `span4` `div`.

`tal:repeat` in `Chameleon` repeats all the elements in the list. If I have 6 element in a list, it generates

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">******</div>
    <div class="span4">******</div>
    <div class="span4">******</div>
    <div class="span4">******</div>
    <div class="span4">******</div>
    <div class="span4">******</div>
    <div class="span4">******</div>
</div>
```

However, this ruins the previous layout.

Is there anyway to do the task only with `Chameleon`?

Comment: I have been waiting to see what the answers would be.   I'm thinking you could do it by injecting python via chameleon.  Typical inner loop and outer loop code. Have you tried anything like that?

Comment: @fatfantasma Yep. I already satisfied the requirement with some dirty hack. The only reason I put the question here is to look for a 'elegant' way to achieve this. :-)

Comment: You should at least post your work around as an answer: )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem basically boils down to [splitting a list into evenly-sized chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) and then using two nested loops to iterate over the "master" list and its "sublists".

Completely untested, I would think something like the following would be a good starting point:

```
<div class="row-fluid" tal:repeat="chunk [l[i*3:(i*3)+3] for i in range((len(l) // 3) + 1) ]">
    <div class="span4" tal:repeat="item chunk"><tal:item replace="item" /></div>
</div>
```